# Ubuntu 12.04 - RubyOnRails - gem install mysql2 seems to install but fails when i do: gem mysql2 - Unknown command mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems, mysql2

I'm a Ror newbe and I'm attempting to create my first webapp with rails. 
I'm encountering a problem when I installed gem mysql2:
This is my actual configuration:

**ruby -v: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]**

**rails -v: Rails 3.2.3**

**gem -v: 1.8.24**

```
michele@michele:~/rails/my_app$ gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.11
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.11...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.3.11...
```

After this I edited the database.yml and I run:

**rake db:create**

it returns:

```
rake aborted!
Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

So, when finally I try to install it I get the error:

```
michele@michele:~/rails/my_app$ gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbch2-adapter, activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter, activerecord-postgis-adapter, activerecord-jdbc-adapter, activerecord-odbc-adapter
```

Obviously I installed properly the others adapters but they don't fit with my needing of mysql2.

Nothing else, I'm just stacked here. :)

Comment: have you run `bundle install`? and does your `Gemfile` include `gem 'myslq2'`

Comment: Yes I did. But I don't know how to check and where to find the Gemfile

EDIT: I think the gemfile shows when i run the $bundle install right? In that case no there isn't any mysql2

Comment: let's say you run `bundle install`, you should see `mysql2` in the list. The `Gemfile` is in your project root.

Comment: Ok understood. 'mysql2' is not on the list. Inside 'Gemfile' i see this:
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a brand new project like so

```
rails new -d=mysql
```

this should initialize the `Gemfile` and the `config/database.yml` with the right values
can you past your Gemfile in your question?

**EDIT**

Replace `gem 'sqlite3'` with `gem 'mysql2'` and `bundle install`. then you'll need to update the `config/database.yml`, take a look at what is generated with in the new project I suggest in the first line

**edit**

remove the socket line, you should be fine with something like:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database:  whatever_is_there
  username: your_username
  password: your_pwd
  host: localhost
  encoding: utf8
```

Comment: Thanks, now the rake is not aborted but I get a misconfiguration error. 
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock' (2)

When I'll fix this everything will be ok. 

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 27):

Better late than never:

1) install mysql support for RoR

on ubuntu `sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev`

2) create rails app

`rails new mysql_app -d mysql`

3) edit `config/database.yml`

to set your username&password&other details.
Mainly i'm writing this not to forget myself... )

Comment: FYI: all I had to do on an Ubuntu machine to get mysql2 gem to install was: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`